Unitary Gauge Removing Goldstone Bosons
The Lagrangian in a spontaneously broken gauge theory at low energies looks like
$$ \frac{1}{2} m^2 ( \partial_\mu \theta - A_\mu )^2 $$
and the gauge transformations look like $\theta \rightarrow \theta + \alpha, A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \partial_\mu \alpha$. Normally, we remove the goldstone field $\theta$ by choosing the unitary gauge, which is $\alpha = - \theta$. However, because $( \partial_\mu \theta - A_\mu )^2$ is gauge-invariant, it doesn't seem like $\theta$ is removed, i.e.
$$ ( \partial_\mu \theta - A_\mu )^2 \rightarrow ( \partial_\mu (\theta - \theta)  - (A_\mu - \partial_\mu \theta))^2 = ( \partial_\mu \theta - A_\mu )^2  $$
Why is it then that the unitary gauge removes the goldstone? Are we implicitly joining this with a field redefinition $A'_\mu = A_\mu - \partial_\mu \theta$ so that the mass term becomes $\frac{1}{2}m^2 A_\mu'^2$?

θ'=0, and $A'_\mu$ remains by itself, as you point out. Scholarpedia.
